# Best practice to avoid passing lots of arguments to function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best practice recommended pattern in Node/Javascript to avoid passing lots of arguments into a function?

```
function create(firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, username, password, dateOfBirth, age) {
   ...
}
```

Should it take in an object?

```
const input = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    ...
};

function create(input) {
}
```

An object seems error prone since there is no validation on the number of properties it should contain and the key names.

Comment: There isn't any validation on the number of arguments you pass either. You can define a function that takes no arguments and still pass stuff to it, mind you there is a default object called `arguments` that you can still access those "hidden" args through. There really isn't any validation at all, other than what you make in anything in js.

Answer (score 1):

> An object seems error prone since there is no validation on the number
>   of properties it should contain and the keys.

I could pass in a function and an HTML element and nothing else into your first function; it would likely fail.

That, at its core, is a fundamental issue with any scripting language. The only way to know you messed up with a function is usually a runtime error. Once it's coded correctly, that's not so much of a concern.

Note that there are languages like TypeScript that are a great help to people that want to enforce this kind of correctness at "compile time".

Answer (score 1):

> Should it take in an object?

Node is almost exclusively used for web servers. In that context, your entry point is typical `req.body`, an object. Who the hell knows what's on that object? So you error handle at the front of server:

```
function bindUser(postBody, callback) {

    var user = {};

    if (!postBody.firstName) {
        return callback(new Error("Missing firstName"));
    }
    user.firstName = postBody.firstName;

    if (!postBody.lastName) {
        return callback(new Error("Missing lastName"));
    }
    user.lastName = postBody.lastName;

    if (!postBody.email) {
        return callback(new Error("Missing email"));
    }
    user.email = postBody.email.toLowerCase();

    callback(null, user);
}
```

Congrats, you've got a known object, and your future debugging has a consistent starting point. Now you build helper functions that do one specific task, e.g. combine a full name:

```
function combineName(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
user.fullName = combineName(user.firstName, user.lastName);
```

Focus your error handling on places that aren't fully contained environments, i.e. I/O and external modules. Outside of that, keep your functions small and specific, and they won't need 10 arguments and a massive walls of guards. Your future debugging self will thank you.

So to specifically address the question:

> What is the best practice recommended pattern in Node/Javascript to avoid passing lots of arguments into a function?

Design your application so that functions don't need 10 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like in your example, you can access the keys using `Object.keys(input)` then you can check the length or do additional validation. You can see if a property is at least 3 characters using something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(input);
keys.every(function(key) {
  return key.length > 3;
});
```